# why is my localhost / wordpress not bringing me to the correct website?

Tags: wordpress, xampp

I just installed the wordpress files in my xampp folder where the should be and created a database. Whenever i try type localhost/wordpress in my browser it gives me back an error.

Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpressC:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpressC:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php on line 10

I tried to change the setup.sample file myself and added the details to my database but that changed nothing.

Comment: You got any screenshots or more information? what does your file structure look like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.